# Do i need to check same-origin in django (ajax)?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

If i dont implement the code for checking that the requests are coming from the same domain as the application is running on as written on this page in the django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/

does that mean that someone can execute csrf requests from other sites? I thought this was built-in functionality in django so you didnt have to check this yourself. You dont have to check this yourself when dealing with forms usually so i guess i dont understand why they would have to implement this functionality in that example.

I have searched on google and read several articles and none of them implement the functionality written in the docs on checking that the requests are coming from the same origin as the application is running on, so i find that strange, they just extract the cookie and send it like i do now.

Whats correct in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to check for CSRF, otherwise someone can send you random data and Bad Things will happen :)

I suggest:

1. enable CsrfViewMiddleware in INSTALLED_APPS
2. on each page, include the [jQuery cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)
3. also on each page, tell jQuery's Ajax system to stick in the cookie on POST requests.  See this gist -- https://gist.github.com/rca/1696408  (not written by me)

The above will get the most security with the least amount of hassle.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. So the jquery library implements functionality to check if the request came from the origin of where the application is running ? I havent been looking much at jquery yet since i like to code without jquery or other libs until i get a good enough understanding of coding ajax/javascript

Comment: @user2959896 No, the jQuery library simply implements functionality to get the value of a cookie. The CSRF token is set as a cookie and the snippet sets it as a header on the request (an alternative to providing it in the POST data), but the `CsrfViewMiddleware` actually checks if the token that is send in the request is a valid token, and thus if the request originated from the right site.

Comment: when reading in the docs again i see that the second example is actually where they are setting the header with the csrf cookie but they still implement the same-origin check, why do they do that if this is handled by the middlewarecomponent?